# Obtendo atributos em HTML com python

Tags: html, python, pandas, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Eu estou querendo obter as informações de `arial-label`, `href` e `title` da tag `a` a baixo:

```
    <a aria-label="AS MAIS TOCADAS NO BAILE FUNK 2019 #1 - SET DE FUNK by Funk 24por48 10 months ago 39 minutes 3,186,126 views" class="yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-video-renderer" href="/watch?v=vTakYj4802U" id="video-title" title="AS MAIS TOCADAS NO BAILE FUNK 2019 #1 - SET DE FUNK">
        <yt-formatted-string aria-label="AS MAIS TOCADAS NO BAILE FUNK 2019 #1 - SET DE FUNK by Funk 24por48 10 months ago 39 minutes 3,186,126 views" class="style-scope ytd-video-renderer">AS MAIS TOCADAS NO BAILE FUNK 2019 #1 - SET DE FUNK</yt-formatted-string>
    </a>
```

Consegui esse trecho HTML através do `selenium` e `BeautifulSoap` (código a baixo)

```
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=self.options)
self.driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=funk+baile')
self.html = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="contents"]')[0].get_attribute('outerHTML')
self.html_musicas = self.soap.findAll(id="video-title", href=True)
```

Como eu poderia conseguir os valores dos atributos citados a cima? (`arial-label`, `href` e `title`)

Answer (score -1):

Consegui apenas fazendo um split na `tag` armazenada em `self.html_musicas` e armazenando-os em um vetor:

```
self.dados_musicas[self.generos] = []
        for dados_tag in self.html_musicas:
            self.dados = str(dados_tag).split('"')
            self.dados_musicas[self.generos].append({self.dados[9]:self.dados[5]})
```

A saida foi essa aqui:

```
[{'MC João - Baile de Favela (KondZilla)': '/watch?v=kzOkza_u3Z8'},]
```